# Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in php

Tags: php, html, css

am stuck with a very cheap problem, when am trying to run my app in localhost its working fine but when I upload it on server then getting error like Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

1)I have properly wrote my email and password
2)I did less Secure app on

Please tell me why its happening

```
 <?php
    
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
    
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
    
    
    try { 
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->isSMTP();                                             
        $mail->Host  = 'smtp.gmail.com;';                    
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
        $mail->Username = '***********';                 
        $mail->Password = '*******';                         
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
        $mail->Port  = 587;
    
        $mail->setFrom('nplus_01@gamil.com', '');        
        $mail->addAddress('nplus_01@gamil.com'); 
        $mail->addAddress('nplus_01@gamil.com', ''); 
        
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
        $mail->Subject = 'Subject'; 
        $mail->Body = "Name is $name <br> Email is $email <br> Subject is $subject <br> Message is $msg"; 
        $mail->AltBody = 'Body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients'; 
        $mail->send();  
        ?>
            <script>
                alert("Message Send Successfully");
            </script>
        <?php
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}"; 
    }
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code-example to the minimum code that is necessary to provoke the authentication error.

Comment: Sir/mam my app is working on localhost

Comment: Good point. Perhaps your server has missing or outdated network / transport libraries.= Any chance you're able to compare the versions of php and it's extensions with your local ones? Maybe that already highlights something.

Comment: Additionally check if you can obtain more error information from Phpmailer. This often contains more concrete information _why_ authentication was not possible.

Comment: I would try setting `$mail->SMTPDebug` to `SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL`, see [this for getting the debug messages out](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/9243b4bb0e24aacd0054a48ec6c7edbd8cc8da8e/src/PHPMailer.php#L414).

Comment: i tried it but still its not working